# org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader in JdbcPagingItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have implemented Batch process in the spring boot using annotation it works as service for me.
I am using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` and reader and processor and writer to read from db and validate in process and inserting into database in the writer.
when one job is launched if i give one more job to run it then batch is failing.
i am getting all parameter dynamicllay from webservice.

`simpleJobLauncher.run(itemDataQualtiyReportJob,jobParameters);`

```
@Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        launcher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        try {
            launcher.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return launcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("DQReports");
        asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(noOfThreads);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }


    @Bean
        public Step step(){
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<ItemDTO,ItemResult>chunk(pageSize)
                .reader(cimm2ItemReader()).listener(CommonItemReadListener())
                .processor(cimm2ItemProcessor()).listener(CommonItemProcessListener())
                .writer(cimm2ItemResultWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipLimit(skipBadRecordsLimit) //default is set to 0
                .skip(FileNotFoundException.class)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .listener(ItemDataQualityStepListener())
                .build();
        }

@Bean
    public ItemReader<ItemDTO> cimm2ItemReader() {
        Cimm2ItemReader itemReader = new Cimm2ItemReader(jdbcTemplate());
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new Cimm2ItemDTOMapper());
        itemReader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider());
        itemReader.setPageSize(pageSize);
        return itemReader;
    }


@Bean
    public ItemProcessor<ItemDTO, ItemResult> cimm2ItemProcessor() {
        return new Cimm2ItemProcessor(jdbcTemplate());
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<ItemResult> cimm2ItemResultWriter() {
        return new Cimm2ItemResultWriter(jdbcTemplate(),objectMapper());
    }


public class Cimm2ItemReader extends JdbcPagingItemReader<ItemDTO>{ 
    private ExecutionContext stepExecutionContext;
    private JobParameters jobParameters;
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private final Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public Cimm2ItemReader(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        super();
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    protected void doReadPage() {
        log.info("--------------------------------Inside Cimm2ItemReader doReadPage Method");
        super.doReadPage();
        log.info("--------------------------------Exit Cimm2ItemReader doReadPage Method");
    }


    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        jobParameters = stepExecution.getJobParameters();
        stepExecutionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();

        //update paging query provider with sql
        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean factory =  new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
        factory.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        String selectClause = getSelectClause();
        String fromClause =   getFromClause();
        String whereClause =  getWhereClause();
        String sortField = "ITEM_ID";
        factory.setSelectClause(selectClause);
        factory.setFromClause(fromClause);
        factory.setWhereClause(whereClause);
        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<String, Order>();
        sortKeys.put(sortField, Order.DESCENDING);
        factory.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        PagingQueryProvider pqp =  null;

        try {
            pqp = factory.getObject();
            super.setQueryProvider(pqp);
            super.afterPropertiesSet();
            //super.setSaveState(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in Cimm Reader Before Step"+e.getMessage());
            throw new ItemDataQualityReportException("Unable to prepare the "
                + "Item master sql to read the item data.",e);
        }
    }
}
```

//----this is jar file code

```
  @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
            if (isSaveState()) {
                startAfterValues = (Map<String, Object>) executionContext.get(getExecutionContextKey(START_AFTER_VALUE));

                if(startAfterValues == null) {
                    startAfterValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                }
            }

            super.open(executionContext);
        }

    @Override
        public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
            super.open(executionContext);
            try {
                doOpen();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ItemStreamException("Failed to initialize the reader", e);
            }
            if (!isSaveState()) {
                return;
            }

            if (executionContext.containsKey(getExecutionContextKey(READ_COUNT_MAX))) {
                maxItemCount = executionContext.getInt(getExecutionContextKey(READ_COUNT_MAX));
            }

            int itemCount = 0;
            if (executionContext.containsKey(getExecutionContextKey(READ_COUNT))) {
                itemCount = executionContext.getInt(getExecutionContextKey(READ_COUNT));
            }
            else if(currentItemCount > 0) {
                itemCount = currentItemCount;
            }

            if (itemCount > 0 && itemCount < maxItemCount) {
                try {
                    jumpToItem(itemCount);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new ItemStreamException("Could not move to stored position on restart", e);
                }
            }

            currentItemCount = itemCount;

        }

    @Override
        protected void doOpen() throws Exception {

            Assert.state(!initialized, "Cannot open an already opened ItemReader, call close first");
            initialized = true;

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

below is the exception.

```
2018-07-12 19:21:23.015 ERROR 24304 — [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep : Encountered an error executing step step in job itemDataQualtiyReport

org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader.open(JdbcPagingItemReader.java:260)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$42c8e250.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at com.unilog.cimm.reports.batch.reader.Cimm2ItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a6d34be.open()
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot open an already opened ItemReader, call close first
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doOpen(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:133)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:146)
… 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is Reader shared? The exception clearly said Cannot open an already opened ItemReader

Comment: `Cannot open an already opened ItemReader` you have a resource collision here. You need to make it one reader per operation.

Comment: Looks like you are using the same reader instance for both jobs. Either share your configuration code so we can help or make sure each job has its own reader instance.

Comment: @NghiaDo:Thank you for quick reply i have updated my code how i will configure step and reader and writer.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine:Thank you for your reply.i am only one reader instance u can see above code

Comment: @Compass: Thank you for ur reply.i am using only one reader instance.i have updated my code how will i configure batch steps,reader,process,writer

Comment: The other alternative is to use `@Prototype` annotation, FYI.

Comment: @Compass:Thank you but it didn't work i tried @Scope("prototype") for reader and processor and writer.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `JdbcPagingItemReader.open` and try to understand when stream is opened the first time and the reason for the second call to `open`; maybe a listener, or the async executor (`cTaskExecutor-2`, check if there is a `cTaskExecutor-1` and reader is not properly close). Debug on your own because I think we have very low possibilities to help you.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci:Thank you for reply this is what the causing issue i am trying to run two jobs at time its conflicting and it's failing.one ctaskexecutor-1 is executing jdbcpagingitemreader its already opened and when ctaskexecutor-2 is try to access them i am getting error please suggest me how can i handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is due to concurrency use of your reader.

> The implementation is thread-safe in between calls
>   to open(ExecutionContext), but remember to use saveState=false if used
>   in a multi-threaded client (no restart available).

So, use `saveState=false` and all should be fine.

Comment: i have added code which causing the issue if i make savestae=false it will go open() method then in the doOpen() method its causing issue.anyway that i can make task executor in the queue